# How to write arrow functions in es6 class?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

```
class ExampleClass{
   constructor(){
   }
   method1 = () =>{
       /* code
       */
   }
}
```

For the above code I get error

```
method1 = () => {`
        ^
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Class methods can't be anonymous, how would you call them? What do you think the benefit of an arrow function is here?

Comment: More importantly, what version of Node are you using?

Comment: remove `=`. check [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: node version v8.7.0

Comment: You can do it inside the constructor, but using `this.method1 = () => {}` instead, but I dont know if that's the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

There is no [native support](http://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--instance-class-fields) for class instance fields just yet. Your best option at the minute is to use a transpiler like Babel which does have [support](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) for this syntax.